# How can I override an inline style with an external css?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to restyle a table generated by an asp.net gridview control.  The problem I have is that the gridview is generating an inline styles.  How do I make the browser render my css rather then the html style attribute?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) in your CSS file.

Comment: IE7 supports !important correctly. IE6 will support !important as long as the same property is not declared again in the same declaration block.

Answer (score 3):

You can use !important; but that doesn't work in all browsers.

Here is an [article on the usage of !important](http://www.yellowjug.com/web-design/the-importance-of-important-in-css/).

Answer (score 2):

You could try appending "!important" on to your css style definitions as per [this article](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html), or following the previous suggestion from Ryan Lanciaux

Answer (score 2):

According to the CSS specification, element selectors have a specificity of 1, class selectors have a specificity of 10, ID selectors have a specificity of 100, and the specificity of inline styles is 1000.  A higher specificity will override a lower specificity, so inline styles always win.  However, there is a way out.  The **!important** declaration overrides all the unimportant declarations.  No matter what the source of the style is, it will lose to anything with the **!important** declaration.

Source: CSS Web Design by Eric A. Meyer.

Comment: The CSS specification says nothing about different selectors having a different value. It simply does a COUNT of different types of selectors, and sorts them by each type from most to least important. If inline styles had a value of 1000 and IDs had a value of 100, then a declaration including 11 IDs would take precedence, however that is not the case. No number of IDs or classes will overtake an inline style. !important is the only method to override an inline style with CSS. Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to override the style with JavaScript. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would make this very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this: http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/09/override-any-css-style-even-inline.html. Use the !Important modifier to make it happen

Answer (score 0):

Are you using themes?  Themes create inline styles.  To get rid of them, you can turn off theming for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView EnableTheming="false" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, inline CSS is always the last style applied to an element, so the inline styles will always override external styles.

If the Gridview's generated styles are giving you fits, have a look at the ASP.NET CSS Friendly Control Adapters (http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/). It's a great project.

Comment: not true, !important has higher specificity than anything else

Answer (score 0):

Inline style has precedence over external styles. It cannot be overriden unless you use **!Important.**